# Weld on Java SE does not use alternative

Tags: java, cdi, weld, weld-se

I have `projectA`, `projectB`, and `projectC` Eclipse Maven projects.

- `ProjectA` contains:

  - `IMyApi` interface.
  - "Empty" `META-INF\beans.xml` file.
- `ProjectB` contains:

  - `IMyConfig` interface.
  - `MyConfigJndi` implementation of `IMyConfig`.
  - `MyApiImpl` implementation of `IMyApi`, with a property `@Inject private IMyConfig config;`.
  - "Empty" `META-INF\beans.xml` file.
- `ProjectC` contains:

  - a `MyConfigAlter` implementation of `IMyConfig`, marked as `@Alternative`.
  - a `Main` class (and method) that initializes Weld SE and retrieves a `IMyApi` bean.
  - a `META-INF\beans.xml` where `MyConfigAlter` is listed in the `alternatives` section.

Now, I run the `Main` class, and the `IMyApi` bean is successfully retrieved (as a `MyApiImpl` instance). But such an instance has been, in its `config` property, injected with a `MyConfigJndi` instance, instead of the alternative version (`MyConfigAlter`)

I am using Eclipse Luna + M2Eclipse.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I found out that using `@Specializes` instead of `@Alternative` solves the issue, but I still think it is not the proper solution (in some situation I may not have access to the "default" implementation).

UPDATE 2:

I am using Weld-se, 2.2.10.Final:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the initialization is simply

```
WeldContainer weld =
  new Weld().
    initialize();
IMyApi myApi =
  weld.
    instance().
    select(
      IMyApi.
        class).
    get();
```

Comment: Could you include some information, like what version of weld you're using, how you're bootstrapping?  The fact that specializes sounds weird to me.

Comment: @JohnAment Thanks for your interest, I added the requested data.

Comment: Of the three jar's you mentioned above, which one does the initialization code live in?

Comment: @JohnAment In `ProjectC`, in the `main` method of the `Main` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selecting an alternative using the `alternatives` element in the `beans.xml` descriptor only affects the corresponding bean archive, i.e. `ProjectC` in your case, as documented in [Declaring selected alternatives for a bean archive](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives_bean_archive). Based on that, this is logical that the `ProjectB` bean archive gets the `MyConfigJndi` implementation injected.

Since CDI 1.2, it is possible to select an alternative globally for the application using the `@Priority` annotation as documented in [Declaring selected alternatives for an application](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives_application).

So in your case, you could write:

```
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.Application)
@Alternative
class MyConfigAlter {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to use `-Dorg.jboss.weld.se.archive.isolation=false` - from http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.2.11.Final/en-US/html/environments.html#_bean_archive_isolation_2

The reason that this happens is that each JAR on the classpath becomes its own bean archive.  Since the CDI spec as of 1.2 does not include an SE specification there is no definition of how the classpath operates in this mode.  This isn't necessarily how an SE app would be designed since you don't have unique classloaders for each JAR.